# What does "kata/as" mean in Luke 22:22?

Tags: word-study, luke

"For the Son of Man goes as it has been determined, but woe to that man by whom he is betrayed!". Luke 22:22.  ESV

1. As. "..the Son of Man goes "since" or "for" it has been determined". In Matthew 19:3 kata is "for". ESV
2. or, As. "the Son of Man goes "as/in the way" it has been determined". Judas' betrayal was part of "in the way", or "in the circumstances in which" it has been determined.
3. As. Does "as" include e.g:

   ```
                   A. Pilate's involvement. Matthew 27:24

                   B. The crowd's shouting. Mark15:13

                   C. The sin of the world. John 1:29?
   ```

Are  A, B and C, along with Judas' involvement, also determined circumstances relating to "as/in the way" in which Jesus went?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to 'in', Professor J.H. Moulton gives a list of the cases governing the prepositions, and says:

> "If *en* represents unity, the order of the frequency of the other
> Prepositions work out thus; *eis,* .64; *ek,* .34; *epi,* .32; *pros,*
> .25; *dia,* .24; *apo,* .24; *kata,* .17;" [and so on] (*Grammar of
> N.T. Greek,* p98)

Now I quote from a different source and just repeat all that it says about *kata* (minus the many scripture reference examples provided):

> x. ***kata*** governs two cases (the Genitive and Accusative) and
> denotes two motions, vertical and horizontal.
>
> 1. With the Genitive it denotes vertical motion, the opposite of *ana,* descent, or detraction from a higher place or plane, and direction to, or against.
> 2. With the Accusative it denotes horizontal motion, along which the action proceeds. Sometimes it includes the purpose or intention. In
>    this connection *eis* marks the more immediate purpose, *pros* the
>    ultimate purpose; and ***kata*** the destination to be reached. It has
>    regard to the duration of the motion and the accordance, conformity or
>    proportion of the two things which such motion thus connects." (*The
>    Companion Bible,* Appendix 104, p149)

Now, I trust Greek scholars will understand exactly what this all means, and be able to arrive at a conclusion. I would hazard a guess that your No. 2 applies -

> "in the way" it has been determined". Judas' betrayal was part of "in
> the way", or "in the circumstances in which" it has been determined."

Answer (score 1):

ESV Luke 22:

> 22
> For the Son of Man goes **as** it has been determined, but woe to that man by whom he is betrayed!".

as
κατὰ (kata)
Preposition
Strong's 2596: A primary particle; down, in varied relations (genitive, dative or accusative) with which it is joined).

it has been determined,
ὡρισμένον (hōrismenon)
Verb - Perfect Participle Middle or Passive - **Accusative** Neuter Singular
Strong's 3724: From horion; to mark out or bound, i.e. to appoint, decree, specify.

In this case, κατὰ is followed by an accusative verb.

Thayer's Greek Lexicon:

> I. With the genitive
> II. With the **accusative**
>
> 1. of place;
> 2. of Time
> 3. it denotes reference, **relation**, proportion, of various sorts;
>    c. according to, agreeably to; in reference to agreement or conformity to a standard

My paraphrase of Luke 22:22a:
The Son of Man will go as it has been agreed upon.

New International Version

> The Son of Man will go as it has been decreed.

The grammatical pattern in Matthew 19:3 is similar:

> And Pharisees came up to him and tested him by asking, “Is it lawful to divorce one’s wife **for** [κατὰ] any [accusative] cause [accusative]?”

My paraphrase:
Is it lawful to divorce one’s wife for any cause according to the standard agreement?

OP: If something were decreed to happen would not all the circumstances that led up to it happening fall under that decree? kata, down.

Yes, in some English sense of *down*. The Greek sense is slightly different,
Strong's Concordance:

> Usage: **gen**: against, **down from**, throughout, by;
> **acc**: over against, among, daily, day-by-day, each day, **according to**, by way of.

Comment: @ Tony Chan If something were decreed to happen would not all the circumstances that led up to it happening fall under that decree? kata, down.

Comment: Good point. I added :)

Answer (score 1):

The proposition κατὰ changes its meaning depending on what follows.  In Luke 22:22 we have κατὰ τὸ ὡρισμένον.  That is, both τὸ and ὡρισμένον are accusative.  Thus, according to BDAG, the meaning of κατὰ is:

> **5. marker of norm of similarity or homogeneity, *according to, in
> accordance with, in conformity with***, eg, Luke 2:22, 39, John 18:31,
> 19:7, Heb 7:5, in accordance with what has been determined, Luke
> 22:22, ...

So, the question here is, according to whose determination?  The answer is actually straight forward - Jesus always acted in accordance with the Torah and the prophecies of the OT.  Note the comments in Bengel's Gnomen -

> Luke 22:22. Κατἀ τὸ ὡρισμένον, according to what was determined) What
> was determined or appointed, we may know from Scripture. See Luke
> 22:37 (“This that is written must yet be accomplished”); Mark 14:21
> (“The Son of Man goeth, as it is written of Him”).—V. g.]

Similarly for the Cambridge commentary -

> 22. **as it was determined** “being delivered by the determinate counsel and foreknowledge of God,” Acts 2:23; Acts 4:27-28. “The Lamb
>     slain from the foundation of the world,” Revelation 13:8. The type of
>     Judas was Ahithophel, Ps. 12:9.

Gill is a little more bold -

> as it was determined; in the counsels and purposes of God, and agreed
> to by Christ in the covenant of grace; see Acts 2:23 the death of
> Christ, the manner of it, and the means by which it was brought about,
> were all predetermined by God; yet this did not, in the least, excuse
> the sin of those concerned in it, nor exempt them from punishment: